# Using VBA how does one determine if a path points to a local hard drive or somewhere on a network?

Tags: vba

I'm having performance issues when users target a network drive as the location to save a file being generated by my macro.

To make things more efficient I'm thinking about identifying if the location is local or on the network and if it is on the network I'll get my macro to save the generated file to a temporary folder and just move it after it's been generated.

Using VBA how would you determine if the path `M:\Folder Name\` is a local folder (quick to manipulate) or is on the network (takes a long time for requests to go through the VPN to manipulate)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the API function `GetDriveTypeA` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getdrivetypea

Put the following code into a module. You can use the function `getDriveType` to get a string describing the drive type or use the function `isNetworkDrive` to simply check if a drive letter points to a network drive.

You can pass the full name of a folder or file as parameter, the routines take only the first character and add `:\`. For example, just call it like this:

```
If isNetworkDrive("M:\Folder Name\") Then
    MsgBox "This is a network drive"
End If
```

If you want to make it more sophisticated, check first if parameter is an UNC path (starting with `\\`)

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
Declare PtrSafe Function apiGetDriveType Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetDriveTypeA" (ByVal nDrive As String) As Long
#Else
Declare Function getDriveType Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetDriveTypeA" (ByVal nDrive As String) As Long
#End If

Function isNetworkDrive(path As String) As Boolean
    Dim driveType As Integer
    driveType = apiGetDriveType(getDrivePath(path))
    isNetworkDrive = (driveType = 4)
End Function

Function getDriveType(path As String) As String
    ' See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getdrivetypea
    Dim driveType As Integer
    driveType = apiGetDriveType(getDrivePath(path))
    
    If driveType = 0 Then
        getDriveType = ""               ' Drive unknown.
    ElseIf driveType = 1 Then
        getDriveType = "(undefined)"               ' No Root (not mounted?)
    ElseIf driveType = 2 Then
        getDriveType = "Removable"
    ElseIf driveType = 3 Then
        getDriveType = "Fixed"
    ElseIf driveType = 4 Then
        getDriveType = "Network"
    ElseIf driveType = 5 Then
        getDriveType = "CD-Rom"
    ElseIf driveType = 6 Then
        getDriveType = "Ram Disk"
    Else
        getDriveType = ""               ' Can never happen according to documentation
    End If
End Function

Function getDrivePath(ByVal path As String)
    GetDrivePath = UCase(Left(path, 1)) & ":\"
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

The underlying function is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getdrivetypea `GetDriveType`.

> Determines whether a disk drive is a removable, fixed, CD-ROM, RAM
> disk, or network drive.