# VBA: How to tell if CurDir is really on the local drive?

Tags: vba

My Excel workbook will export the current sheet to a file. Our systems seems to hang when trying to save to OneDrive or Dropbox, so I'd like to the macro to force the user to save to the local drive only.

The problem is, the user can't always tell if the "current" drive is really on C:. They assume that Desktop or Documents are local, but those can actually be OneDrive folders.

Currently I'm using something like this:

```
 If InStr(1, CurDir, "OneDrive", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        If vbCancel = MsgBox("Please choose a directory on your local Drive", vbOKCancel) Then Exit Sub
        Set FolderDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        With FolderDialog
            .Title = "Select a New Directory"
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            If .Show = -1 Then
                NewDirectory = .SelectedItems(1)
                ChDir NewDirectory
            End If
        End With
End If
```

But that first line should also have a clause for Dropbox. As for adding clauses for other network drives, I'm not sure where to begin!

It would be much simpler if that first line said the equivalent of "If this is not on the local drive, then..."  Is that possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63959106/11683?